# Terraform append route to route table

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, terraform, amazon-vpc, terraform-provider-aws

I have a vpc with shared resources that I want to have multiple other vpcs able to use via vpc peering. Is there a way that I can append a route to the central vpc route table via terraform?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Are these VPCs and route tables managed by your terraform scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible from an architecture point of view and feet AWS specifications than it's possible.

Take a look at the [route](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route), and [vpc_peering](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/vpc_peering_connection) resources.
Also, investigate the existing modules/examples like [this one](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-vpc-peering/blob/master/main.tf) to see the details of how it could be implemented.